# lxc-create undefined symbol: file_to_buf

Tags: debian, lxc, apparmor

I just migrate my stretch installation to a Buster install. I was previously running a LXC 3.x compiled by me and i have uninstall it to take the buster version.

i can create container, start and stop them, but trying to execute lxc-attach this give me this error :

lxc-attach: symbol lookup error: lxc-attach: undefined symbol: file_to_buf

Someone have an idea of what this error means?

I have disable AppArmor temporaly on lxc-create, lxc-attach because this make creation of container impossible.

[Edit]
Lxc version :  1:3.1.0+really3.0.3-8
AppArmor version : 2.12.2-10

Comment: Does running the container with elevated privileges work? `lxc-attach --elevated-privileges -n <container_name>`?

Comment: No it does not work

Comment: What is the error message? Same one as before? Please update your post with this information. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah exactly the same

Comment: After changing the profile, did you restart `apparmor`? `systemctl restart apparmor` What version of `apparmor` do you have installed too? Again please edit your post with what version of `lxc` and `apparmor` you have installed plus whether both are running properly. Thank you.

Comment: Check the output of `ldd /usr/bin/lxc-attach` for libraries not shipped with Debian (typically, anything under `/usr/local`, `/opt` or your home directory). If you touched `/etc/ld.so.conf` or anything under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` for using your self-compiled LXC, you might need to revert that as well.

Comment: Ok i will install a fresh debian and check for file diff one by one.

Comment: It's enough the have locally installed libraries that override the system ones. It's possible even if the configuration of the dynamic loader is untouched. (If you react to a comment, it's worth to notify its author by @mentioning his/her name. And edit the question, don't put info in comments.)